# multi file insert from hive table not working?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hi i have 200 gb of data in one of my hive table backed on HBase.
I have to create 142 different files out of that table currently trying for 3 files only .

**I want to run all query to run parallel at the same time .**
I was trying multi file insert from hive table but getting parse exception .

This is my query that i was trying .

```
FROM  hbase_table_FinancialLineItem

INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/hadoop/user/m6034690/FSDI/FinancialLineItem/Japan.txt'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from hbase_table_FinancialLineItem WHERE FilePartition='Japan'

INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/hadoop/user/m6034690/FSDI/FinancialLineItem/SelfSourcedPrivate.txt'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from hbase_table_FinancialLineItem WHERE FilePartition='SelfSourcedPrivate'


INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/hadoop/user/m6034690/FSDI/FinancialLineItem/ThirdPartyPrivate.txt'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from hbase_table_FinancialLineItem WHERE FilePartition='ThirdPartyPrivate';
```

And after running this i was getting below error.

```
FAILED: ParseException line 7:9 missing EOF at 'from' near '*'
```

Comment: the ParseException is because you are missing semicolon at end of each INSERT

Comment: i want to import into local directory .if i provide semi column then each query will run independently not like multi table insert .

Comment: i dont think it will work like that. If you want to run all hive insert in parallel, try running it as oozie hive action job

Comment: Yea i was also planning to do that .Also i can not created partition in hive as it is pointing to HBase .Just one question any idea how much time lt will take to fetch all 200 gb data from oozie operation if i am planning to create 142 files ?

Comment: depends on resource available. how much cores and memory are there -> check in yarn web console

Comment: 10 crore records and i have enough memory 2 tb space

Comment: if you are running hive action in parallel using fork join it will take time of running one hive action via oozie

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved when you add this `FROM  hbase_table_FinancialLineItem;` at the end of each insert overwrite.